# Redundant files and folder on jekyll site

Tags: git, directory, jekyll

I am learning jekyll with github. When I run:

```
jekyll new portfolio
```

It's just working properly. Let's say the **portfolio** is my root project folder. When I copied my favicon to root folder, that file was automatically copied to `_site` folder, and then when I created my new theme on root folder:

```
jekyll new minimalist-design
```

It gives me redundant folder and files: it's created in root folder and `_site` folder. It also gives me a `.git` folder again on my theme folder.

Why is this happening?

**Here's the full tree from my root folder**

```
portfolio/
├──.gitignore
├──about.md
├──Gemfile
├──Gemfile.lock
├──index.md
├──LICENSE
├──README.md
├──_config.yml
│
├──.git
│  └──//list of repository files
│
├──.sass-cache
│  ├──_base.scssc
│  ├──_layout.scssc
│  ├──_syntax-highlighting.scssc
│  └──minima.scssc
│
├──minimalist-design
│  ├──//It's my created theme folder 
│  ├──.gitignore
│  ├──Gemfile
│  ├──LICENSE.txt
│  ├──minimalist-design.gemspec
│  ├──README.md
│  │
│  ├──.git
│  │  └──//Another repository folder????
│  ├──assets
│  ├──_includes
│  ├──_layouts
│  │  ├──default.html
│  │  ├──page.html
│  │  └──post.html
│  │
│  └──_sass
│
├──_posts
│  └──2016-12-29-welcome-to-jekyll.markdown
│
└──_site
   ├──feed.xml
   ├──feed.xslt.xml
   ├──index.html
   ├──LICENSE
   ├──README.md
   │
   ├──about
   │  └──index.html
   │
   ├──assets
   │  └──main.css
   │
   ├──jekyll
   │
   └──minimalist-design
      ├──//Another my theme folder again????
      ├──Gemfile
      ├──LICENSE.txt
      ├──minimalist-design.gemspec
      └──README.md
```

Answer (score 1):

From [documentation](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/structure/) about `_site` directory:

> This is where the generated site will be placed (by default) once Jekyll is done transforming it. It’s probably a good idea to add this to your `.gitignore` file.

In other words, every file you put in your root folder will be copied into `_site` when running one of the jekyll build command (e.g. `jekyll build` or `jekyll serve`) since it is basically where the built files are generated.

For usual, not-to-be-parsed-and-interpreted files (e.g. files without liquid code or files that are not posts in markdown format), the files are just copied without transformation like you noticed.

---

The `.git` folders in the subdirectories indicate they are independent git repositories: you can check and see their contents are different.